# Summernote position cursor outside inserted node

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am using the summernote WYSIWYG plugin and am adding DOM elements (buttons, links etc) based on user actions such as a button click. The `insertNode` API adds a node to the editor area but it leaves the cursor inside that node (i.e. the cursor is inside the `<button></button>` tags.

How do I ensure that the cursor goes outside this latest insert node?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and the solution I came up with was to insert a space character immediately after the node insertion.

```
editor.insertNode($editable, $(rawHTML)[0]);
editor.insertText($editable, ' ');
```

This actually solved 2 problems for me since I also wanted there to be room between two buttons that are added one right after the other.

I know this isn't exactly what you were looking for but I thought it was the most elegant solution because changing the functionality of `insertNode` could have other repercussions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I shifted to using tinymce for this purpose. It works properly. Since, I am unable to test the answer right away, I will wait for someone else to confirm your solution (or confirm it myself in a couple of days) before accepting.

Comment: This is a simple and nice solution. I used it on a different way in my case : `context.invoke("editor.pasteHTML", newContent + ' ');`

Comment: For me calling insertText after insertNode didn't work as I wanted, because the space character was inserted BEFORE the previously inserted node (summernote v0.8.18)

Answer (score 0):

Use: to save the last position of the cursor

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.saveRange');
```

Then

```
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.restoreRange');
$('#summernote').summernote('editor.focus');
$('#summernote').summernote('pasteHTML', <YOUR HTML>);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me (summernote v0.8.18):

```
$input.summernote("pasteHTML", newContent + "&nbsp;");
```

Credit goes to @Meowcate, which mentioned such approach in comments, however in there the space character was used, which did not worked for me because no cursor was visible after the insertion. I needed to append " " instead of the space.